Algorithm for finding most recent common ancestor in family tree?
I have a few people objects like this:
{
  id: 444,
  ancestors: [
    { id: 142, father: 837, mother: 221, children: [ 844, 371, 473, 113 ] },
    // hundreds more ...
  ]
}

It's easy to find common ancestors between two or more people:
const allAncestors = people.map(({ ancestors }) => ancestors).flat(1);
const commonAncestors = allAncestors.filter(({ id }) => {
  for (const person of persons) {
    if (!person.ancestors.find(ancestor => ancestor.id === id)) 
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});

But how do I find the most recent common ancestor(s)? I imagine there's an algorithm for this written somewhere already, but all my searches bring up results related to binary trees (which are not useful).
Most "recent" means, fewest generations (steps between two people), traversing the tree vertically and never horizontally.

What does "recent" mean here?

"Recent" means "shortest" path through the "tree". As opposed to the "longest" path, or a path to "Adam & Eve".

Hi. Could you please clarify the question? (1) Do you want to find all most-recent common ancestors of all pairs of people? Or do you have a specific pair as input? (2) If A1 and A2 are two common ancestors of X and Y, and assuming A1 is not an ancestor of A2 and A2 is not an ancestor of A1, do you want the algorithm to return both A1 and A2? Or only one of them?

I don't understand the data structure. Does person 837 have 844 as child? Or is 837 the parent of person 142? And how does 444 relate to 837? Can you give an example data structure and at present the same as a graph (drawing)?

@Stef Given an arbitrary number of people, I want to find all the most-recent common ancestors. For example, given full-siblings, I want the parents. Given half-siblings, I want the common parent. Given full 1st-cousins, I want the common grandparents. Given half 1st-cousins, I want the common grandparent (singular). Etc.

@trincot 837 is parent of 142. 837 is an ancestor of 444.

Can you give a full (non-trivial) example of input and expected output for it?

"Recent" is not well defined. As there are several paths involved (from each member of people to a common parent), what should be minimized here? The sum of the lengths of these paths? The minimum length among them? The average? ...some other formula? If you really would need the literal most recent, then you need birth dates...

The problem in determining what "recent" means, since any ancestor having more than 2 children will be recent for them, so

Build the family tree
Find which ancestors having more than 2 children.



const persons = [{
  id: 444,
  ancestors: [
    { id: 142 },
    { id: 143 },
    { id: 144 },
    // hundreds more ...
  ],
},{
  id: 445,
  ancestors: [
    { id: 133 },
    { id: 143 },
    // hundreds more ...
  ]
},{
  id: 446,
  ancestors: [
    { id: 142 },
    { id: 445 },
    // hundreds more ...
  ]
},
{
  id: 447,
  ancestors: [
    { id: 142 },
    { id: 445 },
    { id: 446 },
    // hundreds more ...
  ]
}]


const tree = persons.reduce((r, p) => (p.ancestors.forEach(a => (r[a.id] ??= {})[p.id] = true), r), {});
const result = Object.keys(tree).filter(key => Object.values(tree[key]).length > 1);

console.log(...result);



